# Label x and y axis of grid cells in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna make a game of 2048 but I am facing problem in making x and y axis of each cell of grid. How can I do my work. Please help me!
Url of code
[Url][1][1]: https://codepen.io/Coder-Rohit4326/pen/PoEegyy

Comment: Please do a couple of things. Put code into your question rather than on another site and explain more fully what making the axes means, a picture would help.

Comment: "making x and y axis" implies a two dimensional array (no matter the language), but the actual data structure is not at all clear from your question.